# Installing the gcc file format .tar.gz

Tags: c, gcc, installation

I am installing an old version of gcc, namely 4.2.2, and here it can only be done through tar.gz file. I have already made of .tar.gz the usual folder and met the README document. Who can tell me what I should do, otherwise I don't understand something well. I would be very grateful if you would write all the commands sequentially.

(This directory has been obsoleted for GCC snapshots and CVS access.

For releases the installation documentation is generated from

gcc/doc/install.texi and copied into this directory.

To read this documentation, please point your HTML browser to "index.html". - it was written in the README).

Comment: The README tells you exactly what to do. Follow those instructions.

Comment: _I am installing an old version of gcc, namely 4.2.2_ Why??? It's at least 16 years old? What do you think you'll get from that version that you can't get better/cleaner/easier from a more modern version?

Answer (score 0):

To install GCC 4.2.2 from a tar.gz file, follow these steps:

1. **Extract the Tarball:**
   Use the `tar` command to extract the contents of the tar.gz file:

   ```
   tar -xzvf gcc-4.2.2.tar.gz
   ```

   Replace `gcc-4.2.2.tar.gz` with the actual name of your tar.gz file.
2. **Navigate to the Extracted Folder:**
   Enter the directory that has been created after extraction:

   ```
   cd gcc-4.2.2
   ```
3. **Configure the Build:**
   Run the configure script to prepare the build:

   ```
   ./configure
   ```

   This step will set up the build configuration based on your system.
4. **Compile the Source Code:**
   Use `make` to compile the source code:

   ```
   make
   ```

   This step will compile the GCC source code.
5. **Install GCC:**
   Install GCC using the following command:

   ```
   make install
   ```

   This command will install GCC on your system.
6. **Verify Installation:**
   To verify that GCC 4.2.2 is installed, you can use:

   ```
   gcc --version
   ```

   This command will display the installed GCC version. If successful, it should show GCC 4.2.2.

Remember, the installation process might require administrative privileges, so you might need to use `sudo` before certain commands if you encounter permission issues.

Please make sure to adjust the commands if the file or folder names differ from what I've provided.

Comment: what should I do if I got a lot of compilation errors when using the make command?

Comment: @OnlyShadow: Cry would be a good start.  You need to analyze the errors.  You might need to specify the bootstrap compiler should work in C90 mode rather C11 (which is the default for more recent versions of GCC).  You should also consider whether you want to install GCC 4.2.2 as the main compiler or whether it should be in another location.  Were it me, I'd place it in `/opt/gcc/v4.2.2` or thereabouts, and I'd configure it so that's where it expects to be (`./configure --prefix=/opt/gcc/v4.2.2 …`).  In case of doubt, add `CC="gcc --std=c90"` to the configure command.

Comment: At least with GCC 4.2.2 you don't need a working C++ compiler.  Note that [GCC 4.2.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) was released in October 2007.  You may have to worry about the pre-requisite libraries, too.  Those might be GMP, MPC, MPFR, ISL.  And you probably need the versions from the time when GCC 4.2.2 was released.