# compilation errors when using make when installing gcc

Tags: c, gcc, gnu-make

I have already turned the `.tar.bz2` (I was installing gcc-4.2.2) file into a folder, entered this folder, and used its `./configure`, wrote `make` on the command line. It was after `make` that I got a lot of compilation errors. At the end, I was given the message:

```
make[3]: *** [Makefile:2181: toplev.o] Error 1

make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/kali/Downloads/gcc-4.2.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc'

make[2]: *** [Makefile:4519: all-stage1-gcc] Error 2

make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kali/Downloads/gcc-4.2.2'

make[1]: *** [Makefile:15591: stage1-bubble] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kali/Downloads/gcc-4.2.2'

make: *** [Makefile:651: all] Error 2
```

What should I do to successfully install gcc without errors?

[image: obnoxious screen shot]

Comment: Are you unable to install a pre-built GCC package? That's by far more usual than building GCC from source, which can be tricky.

Comment: Note also that you've shown a bunch of *warnings*, but these are not fatal.  It's unclear what the actual error was.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: What platform are you building on?  Does it already have a gcc installed (run gcc -v).  The only reason that I ask, is that current gcc is up to version 13.  version 4.8.4 dates from 2007.   You may have better luck building a more modern version of gcc.  If you really need an archaic version, you may need to go backwards slowly.

Comment: See [Installing the GCC file format `.tar.gz`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77573318/15168) for some context for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your first set of errors starts with `make[3]: *** [Makefile:2181: toplev.o] Error 1` — which is a pity because the useful information comes before that line of output.  Quite apart from being almost unreadable, the image does not contain the error message — it contains various warnings which can be (of necessity, must be) ignored.

When I tried a build of GCC 4.2.2 on a machine running RHEL 7 ("Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)" according to `/etc/Redhat-release`), using the GCC 13.2.0 compiler that I compiled, and running without parallel building so that messages are readable and not interleaved), I get:

```
gcc   -g -fkeep-inline-functions -DIN_GCC   -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-format-attribute -fno-common   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc -I../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/. -I../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/../include -I../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/../libcpp/include  -I../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../libdecnumber    \
  -DTARGET_NAME=\"x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu\" \
  -c ../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/toplev.c -o toplev.o
In file included from ../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/toplev.c:30:
../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/basic-block.h: In function ‘single_succ_edge’:
../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/system.h:576:55: warning: ISO C does not support ‘__FUNCTION__’ predefined identifier [-Wpedantic]
  576 |    ((void)(!(EXPR) ? fancy_abort (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__), 0 : 0))
      |                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/basic-block.h:622:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘gcc_assert’
  622 |   gcc_assert (single_succ_p (bb));
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
…
… 74 lines omitted
…
../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/toplev.c: At top level: 
../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/toplev.c:539:1: error: redefinition of ‘floor_log2’
  539 | floor_log2 (unsigned HOST_WIDE_INT x)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/toplev.c:58:
../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/toplev.h:173:1: note: previous definition of ‘floor_log2’ with type ‘int(long unsigned int)’
  173 | floor_log2 (unsigned HOST_WIDE_INT x)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~
../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/toplev.c:574:1: error: redefinition of ‘exact_log2’
  574 | exact_log2 (unsigned HOST_WIDE_INT x)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~
../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/toplev.h:179:1: note: previous definition of ‘exact_log2’ with type ‘int(long unsigned int)’
  179 | exact_log2 (unsigned HOST_WIDE_INT x)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~
…
… 77 lines omitted
…
../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/toplev.c:1814:65: warning: unquoted option name ‘-Os’ in format [-Wformat-diag]
 1814 |       warning (0, "-fprefetch-loop-arrays is not supported with -Os");
      |                                                                 ^~~
../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/toplev.c:1837:20: warning: unquoted option name ‘-fstack-protector’ in format [-Wformat-diag]
 1837 |       warning (0, "-fstack-protector not supported for this target");
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [Makefile:2181: toplev.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/work1/jleffler/tmp/gcc-4.2.2-obj/gcc'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:4520: all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/work1/jleffler/tmp/gcc-4.2.2-obj'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:15592: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/work1/jleffler/tmp/gcc-4.2.2-obj'
make: *** [Makefile:15876: bootstrap] Error 2
```

The good news is that the make messages at the end match what you're seeing very closely (off-by-one in the line numbers for `all-stage1-gcc` and `stage1-bubble`).  That means I'm probably seeing the same problem you are.

The other good news is that GCC 13.2.0 has told us where to look:

**`toplev.c`**

```
 538 int
 539 floor_log2 (unsigned HOST_WIDE_INT x)
 540 {
…
 573 int
 574 exact_log2 (unsigned HOST_WIDE_INT x)
 575 {
```

**`toplev.h`**

```
172 extern inline int
173 floor_log2 (unsigned HOST_WIDE_INT x)
174 {
…
178 extern inline int
179 exact_log2 (unsigned HOST_WIDE_INT x)
180 {
```

Ugh!  Inline function semantics is one of the areas where GCC has changed over the years.  The [Changes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.2/changes.html) document for GCC mentions forthcoming changes in the way inline functions are handled.

There are several ways we could try fixing this.  I think the most reliable one is to forego the inline function definitions.  Here's the context diff (patch file) I created:

```
--- toplev-20070901.092830.h    2007-09-01 09:28:30.000000000 -0600
+++ toplev.h    2023-12-06 22:13:45.229614401 -0700
@@ -169,6 +169,7 @@
 #  define CTZ_HWI __builtin_ctz
 # endif
 
+#ifdef DO_IT_THE_OFFICIAL_WAY
 extern inline int
 floor_log2 (unsigned HOST_WIDE_INT x)
 {
@@ -180,6 +181,11 @@
 {
   return x == (x & -x) && x ? (int) CTZ_HWI (x) : -1;
 }
+#else
+extern int floor_log2 (unsigned HOST_WIDE_INT x);
+extern int exact_log2 (unsigned HOST_WIDE_INT x);
+#endif /* DO_IT_THE_OFFICIAL_WAY */
+
 #endif /* GCC_VERSION >= 3004 */
 
 /* Functions used to get and set GCC's notion of in what directory
```

With that, the compilation continued and got far further.  It is still very noisy.  The errors I showed were close to line number 113,000 in the build log file.

After letting the compilation run for a while, the warnings are dramatically reduced once the code starts compiling its own source code.  However, you aren't completely out of the woods yet — and the error messages from GCC 4.2.2 are nowhere near as comprehensive as those from GCC 13.2.0 — it's one of the areas where the GCC team has done a fantastic job improving the product.

```
rm -f 32/libgcov.a
ar  rc 32/libgcov.a libgcc/32/_gcov.o libgcc/32/_gcov_merge_add.o libgcc/32/_gcov_merge_single.o libgcc/32/_gcov_merge_delta.o libgcc/32/_gcov_fork.o libgcc/32/_gcov_execl.o libgcc/32/_gcov_execlp.o libgcc/32/_gcov_execle.o libgcc/32/_gcov_execv.o libgcc/32/_gcov_execvp.o libgcc/32/_gcov_execve.o libgcc/32/_gcov_interval_profiler.o libgcc/32/_gcov_pow2_profiler.o libgcc/32/_gcov_one_value_profiler.o
ranlib 32/libgcov.a
/work1/jleffler/tmp/gcc-4.2.2-obj/./gcc/xgcc -B/work1/jleffler/tmp/gcc-4.2.2-obj/./gcc/ -B/opt/gcc/v4.2.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/opt/gcc/v4.2.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /opt/gcc/v4.2.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /opt/gcc/v4.2.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include -O2  -O2 -g -O2  -DIN_GCC    -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition  -isystem ./include  -fPIC -g -DHAVE_GTHR_DEFAULT -DIN_LIBGCC2 -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED  -I. -I. -I../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc -I../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/. -I../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/../include -I../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/../libcpp/include  -I../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../libdecnumber -m32 -fexceptions -fvisibility=hidden -DHIDE_EXPORTS -c ../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/unwind-dw2.c -o libgcc/32/unwind-dw2.o
In file included from ../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/unwind-dw2.c:338:
../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/config/i386/linux-unwind.h: In function ‘x86_fallback_frame_state’:
../../gcc-4.2.2/gcc/config/i386/linux-unwind.h:142: error: field ‘info’ has incomplete type
make[4]: *** [libgcc.mk:1191: libgcc/32/unwind-dw2.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/work1/jleffler/tmp/gcc-4.2.2-obj/gcc'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1540: stmp-multilib] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/work1/jleffler/tmp/gcc-4.2.2-obj/gcc'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:4520: all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/work1/jleffler/tmp/gcc-4.2.2-obj'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:15592: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/work1/jleffler/tmp/gcc-4.2.2-obj'
make: *** [Makefile:15876: bootstrap] Error 2
```

Bother!  We need to do a similar analysis to what I did before, working out where the `struct siginfo` (beware of Grammarly fixing source code!) definition should be coming from:

**`linux-unwind.h`**

```
137     {
138       struct rt_sigframe {
139     int sig;
140     struct siginfo *info;
141     void *puc;
142     struct siginfo info;
143     struct ucontext uc;
144       } *rt_ = context->cfa;
145       /* The void * cast is necessary to avoid an aliasing warning.
146          The aliasing warning is correct, but should not be a problem
147          because it does not alias anything.  */
148       sc = (struct sigcontext *) (void *) &rt_->uc.uc_mcontext;
149     }
```

POSIX [`<signal.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html)
specifies:

> ⌦ The `<signal.h>` header shall define the `siginfo_t` type as a structure, which shall include at least the following members: ⌫

There's a decent chance that on some systems, the header contains `typedef struct siginfo siginfo_t;` or equivalent, and changing the two occurrences of `struct siginfo` to `siginfo_t` will fix the code.

This is the sort of difficulty you should expect when trying to port 16-year-old code to a modern system, especially when the code gets as intimate with the o/s as GCC does.

Here's a patch for `gcc/config/i386/Linux-unwind.h`:

```
--- config/i386/Linux-unwind-20060227.102626.h  2006-02-27 10:26:26.000000000 -0700
+++ config/i386/linux-unwind.h  2023-12-06 22:38:31.172287855 -0700
@@ -137,9 +137,17 @@
     {
       struct rt_sigframe {
    int sig;
+#ifdef DO_IT_THE_OFFICIAL_WAY
    struct siginfo *pinfo;
+#else
+    siginfo_t *pinfo;
+#endif /* DO_IT_THE_OFFICIAL_WAY */
    void *puc;
+#ifdef DO_IT_THE_OFFICIAL_WAY
    struct siginfo info;
+#else
+   siginfo_t info;
+#endif /* DO_IT_THE_OFFICIAL_WAY */
    struct context uc;
       } *rt_ = context->cfa;
       /* The void * cast is necessary to avoid an aliasing warning.
```

With those two changes, the build of GCC 4.2.2 completed for me on the RHEL 7 machine.  YMMV, depending in part on what platform you are porting it to.